# Displaying a back button when opening a new Activity - Android

Tags: android

Hey guys I have a chart being generated by `achartengine` and from that a `intent` is returned and started within the main source code.  When I start the `Intent` it opens the bar graph up, but it opens it up and replaces everything else.  I have tried making my `clear button` show within that activity but I am having trouble.

So my question is, how do I display a button and give it properties when I start a new activity?

David

UPDATE: Source Code:

Here is the calling within a function once a specific function is called:

```
            /************
            * define new object with BarGraph class to get results and than display with the bar graph
            ************/
       BarGraph bar = new BarGraph();
            /***********
             * create intent with the results
            ************/
       Intent barIntent = bar.getIntent(this, results);
            /***********
             * start the activity from results
            ***********/
       startActivity(barIntent);
```

Here is the BarGraph source:

....includes.....

```
public class BarGraph {

    public Intent getIntent(Context context, double [] imgResults){

        double y[] = imgResults;  // store results from processed image {25,10,15,20};

        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pass levels (80% or lower is a fail)");
        for(int i=0; i < y.length; i++){
            series.add("Bar"+(i+1),y[i]);
        }

        ....chart functions.......
     Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataSet, mRenderer,Type.DEFAULT);

                return intent;
    }
}
```

This returns the chart intent which in my main source, it starts it.  I am having difficulty with setting a corresponding button with that intent.

Suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: If another activity replaces your activity then why do you need a back button on screen ? You can easily come back pressing back button of the phone.

Comment: Well I want the user to be able to view two different result forms, one the bar graph and hit back and be able to see a simpler form but also be able to move forward again

Comment: What's the problem in adding a button to the bar graph activity ?

Comment: "Well I want the user to be able to view two different result forms, one the bar graph and hit back and be able to see a simpler form but also be able to move forward again" -- then why isn't this two tabs? Or just using the device's own BACK button?

Comment: Well I have a separate class and the Intent on the main source code reaches out to that and the other class returns the bar graph and the main source code activates the activity.  So I am confused on how to add a button to that since it is creating a new screen?

Comment: @DavidBiga why do you need a back button for that. you can use hardware button button as suggested by commonsware

Comment: Sorry did not realize that, this is going to go on a touch screen only device with no buttons.

Comment: @DavidBiga-Android requires a back button in the system navigation bar if there are no hardware buttons. Unless this is for a custom ROM.

Comment: Ya I know I am just designing software, so could you give me a good source to check out or help me out in anyway?

Comment: @DavidBiga Not enough information in your update to understand why you are having difficulty. If your barIntent is in your Activity's local variables set, you should be able to create it anywhere prior to using  it in startActivity a onClick handler. IF you are asking to change GraphicalActivity (the one where the chart is graphed) - you only have one visible activity at a time, but the code is open source so you would have to change that to add in anything.

Comment: @MorrisonChang How would I go about editing the graphical end?